# SAS - How to separate a string with variable substring into multiple columns

Tags: variables, split, sas

I have a dataset containing a variable X, made up of multiple numbers separated by a comma. The number of item is different among rows. I created a count words. Now I would like to see the numbers in different columns.

Here the example:

```
    X          Num_of_X       Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4   ... Varn
3,10,165         3             3       10     165
   1             1             1
  15,100         2            15      100
10,52,63,90      4            10       52      63      90
```

I tried this way:

```
%let max_num_X=max(num_of_x);

data have;
set have;
 length var1-var&max_num_X $10.;
 array Var(&max_num_X) $;
do i=1 to &max_num_X;
 Var[i]=scan(X,i,',');
 output;
 end;
run;
```

Could you help me?
Thank you

Comment: You need to put the actual maximum value of NUM_OF_X from HAVE into the macro variable. All you did was put the literal text max.... into the macro variable. So that will end up generating invalid SAS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this

```
data have;
input X :$20.;
datalines; 
3,10,165    
1           
15,100      
10,52,63,90 
;

data long;
   set have;
   n = _N_;
   do i = 1 to countw(X, ',');
      xx = scan(X, i, ',');
      output;
   end;
run;

proc transpose data = long out = want(drop=_:) prefix=Var;
   by n;
   id i;
   var xx;
run;
```

Comment: It does work! Thank you! Could you explain me better the steps?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a macro to find the maximum number and create the variables:

```
%macro create_vars();
    proc sql noprint; select max(countw(X)) into :max_num_X from have; quit;
    data have; set have;
       %do i = 1 %to &max_num_X.; Var&i. = scan(X,&i.,','); %end;
    run;
%mend;
%create_vars();
```